# Can't open phpmyadmin in ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I flowed step from following link successfully.

```
https://www.ostechnix.com/install-phpmyadmin-with-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/
```

Now i am trying to open phpmyadmin in browser with this URL

```
http://192.168.1.113/phpmyadmin
```

But it is so me below error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.1.113 Port 80
```

i have installer phpmyadmin successfully then after why it says then `not found` i am not getting this issue

after that i did 
`gksu gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

and added `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` line at end of file.

now i can see something different[image] error.

if anyone can help me please do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try http://192.168.1.113/phpMyAdmin

Comment: @iCoders tried but not working

Comment: you can use https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ this so this folder you have to upload to server www/html folderand access phpmyadmin

Comment: i ma using Ubuntu system and now i am getting deferent error

Comment: in ubuntu also working you have ot unzip folder and upload to server var/www/html/

Comment: @iCoders see i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Follow this topic

https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486

I tried it and everything work correctly on my pc,

If you have any problem with fixing it, just try to remove what you have install and follow the above URL.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your main problem is that there is no PHP installation on your system. When a Apache is installed but no PHP interpreter the Apache is just outputting the PHP code.

To fix this you just have to install PHP and in your case you should also install the extensions PHPMyAdmin suggests.

```
apt-get install php php-mysql php-mbstring php-zip
```

After this restart your Apache2 and refresh the PHPMyAdmin browsertab.